# Vue 3 || Vite || Vuex || if running npm run dev, I will get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'store' before initialization' in the console

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vite

I don't know why Iam getting this error. Everything should work fine, or?

This is how my main.js looks like

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
import './index.css'
import { io } from "socket.io-client"

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
export const socket = io("http://localhost:3000/", {
    reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
    auth: {
        token: token
    }
    // query: {
    //   "my-key": "my-value"
    // }
})

const customAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
    timeout: 10000

})

if (token) {
    customAxios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    customAxios.defaults.headers.common = {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
} else {
    customAxios.defaults.headers.common = {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

export default customAxios
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(socket)
    .mount('#app')
```

My store/index.js looks like this:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import loggedInUser from './modules/loggedInUser'
import createChat from './modules/createChat'

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {

  },
  modules: {
    loggedInUser,
    createChat
  }
})
```

I tried also to modify my index.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import loggedInUser from './modules/loggedInUser'
import createChat from './modules/createChat'

const store= createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {

  },
  modules: {
    loggedInUser,
    createChat
  }
})
export default store;
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fe-chat2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 8081",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^8.1.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.16",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.9.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "vite": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

So why I am getting "main.js?t=1637369525686:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'store' before initialization
at main.js?t=1637369525686:44" in the console?
Anyone knows why Iam experincing this kind of problem?

THX a lot :)

Comment: Does it works if you remove for testing purpose `loggedInUser` and `createChat` from `createStore()` ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing app.use(pinia) and app.use(router) as I found on some sites did not work. I accidentally discovered a solution while switching my imports

**I managed to make it work by** changing the order of these 2 imports in the main file:

```
//router needs to come first
import router from './router'
import App from './App.vue'
```